# The right way of creating a IloObjective

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am writing a program in C++ using cplex. I am able to read the information from a file such that I create one matrix which contains the percentages and two arrays containing the sellingprice and the buying price. :

```
double ** percents;
double * prices;
double * sellprices;
prices = (double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double ));
sellprices = (double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double ));
percents = (double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
for(i=0; i < n; i++) 
    percents[i] = (double *)malloc(m*sizeof(double));
```

Furthermore, I created two arrays in which should be optimised in the end.

```
IloNumVarArray X(env);
IloNumVarArray Y(env);

for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
        X.add(IloNumVar(env));
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        Y.add(IloNumVar(env));

model.add(IloMaximize(env, sellprices[i]*X[i] - prices[i]*Y[i]));
```

Is this the right way to create the objective or not?

Answer (score 3):

You need to compute

```
sum_i sellprices[i] * X[i]
```

and

```
   sum_i prices[i] * Y[i]
```

If you want prices and sellprices to be plain c-arrays, you need an IloExpr

```
IloExpr totalSales(env);
IloExpr costOfGoodsSold(env);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   totalSales += sellprices[i]*X[i];
   costOfGoodsSold += prices[i]*Y[i];
}
model.add(IloMaximize(env, totalSales - costOfGoodsSold));
```

Now, you can avoid the mallocs and the loops by using IloNumArrays for sellprices and prices

```
sellprices = IloNumArray(env, n);
prices = IloNumArray(env, n);
model.add(IloMaximize(env, IloScalProd(sellPrices, X) - IloScalProd(prices, Y)));
```

If you don't want to use IloNumArray, you should at least try std::vector.